# Throw inside Catch block, StackTrace information lost

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, stack-trace, throw

The last paragraph of [the remark section of VB Throw Statement doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/throw-statement#remarks) says:

> The Throw statement resets the call stack for the expression exception. If expression is not provided, the call stack is left unchanged. You can access the call stack for the exception through the StackTrace property.

So I expect when an exception happens in my following code, I can see the complete stacktrace information in VS debugging view, since I haven't put `ex` after `Throw`.

```
For Each item in someEF6LinqQuery
    Try
        'do many things with the item
    Catch ex As Exception
        ex.Data("AKeyForDebugging") = item.KeyColumn
        Throw
    End Try
Next
```

But it turns out the first line number I got in the stacktrace is just that of the `Throw` line.

I have to comment out the Try statement and the Catch block so that I can see the line number where , say the NullReferenceException, was actually thrown.

I want to know what I have misunderstood.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do there, anyway you can declare a try/catch block C#-style (`Try Catch End Try` -> without `ex`) and assign a StackTrace object to a local variable in the catch block (e.g., `dim st = new StackTrace()`). The Stack Frames should be all there (if that's what you need).

Comment: I had the same expectation you did, but it turns out that (based on some simple testing) if the exception originates in the same routine, the original throw site is lost.  If the exception originates in a different routine, then the original throw site is retained.

Comment: For a typical release build, this wouldn't matter because line numbers are stripped anyway, so the call stack would be accurate.